# XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, nusoap

I'm trying to create a webservice with PHP and nuSoap but everytime I try to execute it I'm getting the error:

> XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Not well-formed (invalid token)

Can anyone see what's wrong?

service.php

```
<?php
require 'lib/nusoap.php';

$server = new nusoap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("casamitger" . "urn:casamitger");
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'urn:casamitger';
include 'functions.php';

//getAvailabilities
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('Availabilities','complexType','struct','all','',array(
   'StartDate' => array('name' => 'StartDate', 'type' => 'xsd:date'), 
   'EndDate' => array('name' => 'EndDate', 'type' => 'xsd:date'),
   'State' => array('name' => 'State', 'type' => 'xsd:string'), 
));

$server->wsdl->addComplexType('ArrayOfAvailabilities', 'complexType', 'array', '', 'SOAP-ENC:Array', array(), array(
    array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType', 'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Availabilities[]')), 'tns:Availabilities');


$server->register(
    'getAvailabilities',
    array(
        "SessionID"       => 'xsd:string', 
        "AccommodationId" => 'xsd:integer'
    ),
    array("return" => 'tns:ArrayOfAvailabilities')
);

    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

functions.php

```
function getAvailabilities($sessionID, $accommodation_code) {
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "casamitger");
    if (authenticate($sessionID)) {
        $user = getUser($sessionID);
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT count(AccommodationId) c FROM UserAccommodations WHERE AccommodationId = '$accommodation_code' AND CompanyId = '$user'") or die();
        $row = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
        $count = $row->c;
        if ($count > 0) {
            $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT StartDate,EndDate,State FROM Availabilities WHERE AccommodationId = '$accommodation_code'") or die();
            $n = 0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
                $result[$n]['StartDate'] = $row->StartDate;
                $result[$n]['EndDate'] = $row->EndDate;
                $result[$n]['State'] = $row->State;
                $n++;
            }
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

and the client.php

```
<?php

require 'lib/nusoap.php';
include 'functions.php';

$sessionid          = '1234';
$accommodation_code = '83081';

$client = new nusoap_client("http://192.168.8.155:8090/ws/service.php?wsdl");

$availabilities = $client->call(
    'getAvailabilities', 
    array(
        "SessionID"       => "$sessionid", 
        "AccommodationId" => "$accommodation_code",
    )
);

if ($client->fault) {
    echo 'Fault';
} else {
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        echo $err;
    } else {
        print_r($servicetypes);
    }
}
?>
```

If I call the method getAvailabilities() directly it works but it doesn't through the web service, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: To say what is wrong with the XML payload you need to show the XML payload - not the code that is creating it. Also if the error message is unclear to you, please contact the vendor of that software library for your support options to get support in understanding the meaning of the error message. Those projects live and die from the feedback they get from their users.

Comment: I'm just getting a bunch of weird ASCII characters.

Comment: That could mean that HTTP compression is in use. Does it start with `GZ` or similar?

Comment: No, it starts with ÍÑ-No

Comment: Well this is kind of embarrasing but I've found the problem, there was an "echo" in the getUser() function, I've removed it and now it's working fine. Thank you anyway.

Comment: So good we talked about it I'd say :) Happy coding.